# Select Panel Node Layout on Node edit form

Tags: 7, panels

I have multiple different layout variations all for the same node type, is it possible to select which one will be used from the node edit form?

For example I have a node type of product which has the following layout variations:

- 2 Column
- 3 Column
- 2 Column Hybrid

On the node edit for I would have then have a drop down (or something else) which allows me to select one of the variations listed above. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Panels (presumption based on the column names), so this is very easy to achieve.

In Page Manager, enable and edit node_view. Create a new panel variant. Enable Selection Rules for the variant. Add the selection rules `"node_type = product"` and `"field_layout = 2 column"`.

Then carry on through the rest of the config, ie choose 2 column layout and put in your fields/blocks/etc. You will then have to create 2 more variants (or clone and edit the current variant), changing the selections rules and layout to suit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Panelizer for this purpose http://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer. Check this article for details http://drupalwatchdog.com/2/1/panelizer-layouts

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using a combination of taxonomy and selection rules in Panels:

- Create multiple layouts (variants)
- Create matching terms in a "Layout" vocabulary.
- Use the term as a selection rule for each layout.
- Assign the vocabulary to each content type that should allow that layout choice. You can make it a dropdown or radio buttons (not checkboxes, obviously!).

Authors can then choose which layout to use when creating/editing a node.