# Select Panel Node Layout on Node edit form-further question

Tags: theming, nodes, forms, panels

I have a site where the content creators have the ability to select between 4 node layouts before they are able to add content to the node. I have managed to figure out how to do this via this post.

[Select Panel Node Layout on Node edit form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35513/select-panel-node-layout-on-node-edit-form)

However, the layout only takes effect when the node is saved. I was wondering if there is a way to select the layout from the field as the answer in the link suggests, but then have it automatically load the layout with out having to save.